# How to get current element in html method call in Angular 2

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using the primefaces datatable component in Angular 2.
I am trying to make a generic visible column selector.
The p-column element has a "hidden" property I would like to set with a method searching if that column is my visible columns array.

Something like that :

**MyCustomList.html**

```
<p-dataTable [value]="items">
    <p-column [hidden]="isHidden(this)" header="Name" field="name"></p-column>
    ... other columns ...
</p-dataTable>
```

**MyCustomList.ts**

```
isHidden(column) {
    //simple test for example
    if (column.field === 'name') {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The point is that *column* is not the element "p-column" itself, but the "MyCustomList" component itself, so impossible to know on which column I am. And of course, there is no *$event* available here.

Since I want something generic, I would like to avoid defining a #tag to pass to my method. Is there a specific keyword like *this* or *$event* I could use here?

Thanks for your anwsers!

Comment: if `name` column has to be hidden? just  use a Boolean there.

Comment: @Asterius Why do you want to avoid #tag?

Comment: @Nikhil For genericity. For writing faster, with less code. Why adding a #tag, check that it is different on all columns, and then passing that tag name in my method, if I can simply copy/past that code...?

Comment: @Aravind, the boolean has to be defined, named, or accessed through another structure like a map. It is the same problem I would like to avoid. How to use a generic method, without having to pass a specific value (or a specific boolean) to my method

Answer (score 0):

You can set the same variable name and then pick up the columns using `ViewChildren`.

So simply do:

```
@ViewChildren('column') columns: QueryList<any>;
```

And then find your column with:

```
this.columns.filter((column) => {


  if (column.field === 'name') {

    // This is the column you want to use.
  }
})[0];
```

Comment: I am not sure about how to wire that in the html. But maybe the solution is indeed to remove the html binding to set the "hidden" property programatically